# Split string on whitespace but exclude inside HTML tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this decoded html string  `<div style=\"text-align:right; \">test1 <strong>test2 </strong>test3 test4 test5</div>`

I need to split them in whitespaces but should not split spaces in html tags, so I will have the following split in 5. I'm not a regex guy so I need help.

```
<div style=\"text-align:right;\">test1

<strong>test2

</strong>test3

test4

test5</div>
```

EDIT: I included `</strong>` and add another line to make another point.

Comment: What are you actually doing? When processing HTML its always best to use an HTML parser and I'm wondering if what you actually want could be best done that way. Also you appear to have lost a `</strong>` closing tag. Is that deliberate and if so could you give the logic of why it has gone...

Comment: Your `<strong>` tag is unclosed, and `text-align` cannot have any spaces in it. Assuming you want to separate them on the page, but not in your code, 'splitting' them on the page should be done by using a class on the `<strong>` tag with margins.

Comment: I apologize i forgot to include closing tag of strong, but let me fix that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out kinda ugly but works, probably better way than this (may just use htmlagility pack):

```
        List<String> finalList = new List<string>();
        bool insideHtml = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string[] test = "<div style=\"text - align:right; \">test1 <strong>test2 </div>".Split(' ');

        foreach (string t in test)
        {
            if (t.Contains("<"))
            {
                sb.Append(" " + t);
                insideHtml = true;
                if (t.Contains(">"))
                {
                    finalList.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                    insideHtml = false;
                }
            }
            else if (t.Contains(">"))
            {
                sb.Append(" " + t);
                finalList.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
                insideHtml = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (insideHtml)
                {
                    sb.Append(" " + t);
                }
                else
                {
                    finalList.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: BTW can I manipulate the code that can wrap a span tag for test1 to test5 excluding the html tags

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit, can't seem to understand what you are asking. Also, at a certain point with these rules it may be better to switch over and use HTML Agility Pack ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack ). The more rules you add to the parse options the more this turns into a house of cards so be careful.

Comment: from the example above, I will then insert a span tag in each string array but inside the existing html tag example on string array 1 the results would be <div style=\"text-align:right;\"><span>test1</span>

Comment: this works on javascript but not on c# please check str.split(/(<\/?\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>)/gim)

Answer (score 0):

You can split based on `' <'` or `'> '`:

```
string value = <div style=\"text - align:right; \">test1 <strong>test2 </strong>test3</div>;
string[] listHtml = Regex.Split(value, "( <)|(> )");
```

Comment: What if he has <div class="downvoteOP"> test1 test2 test3</div>

Comment: @TravisActon I updated the answer to split based on `"> "` or `" <"`

Comment: so what would happen with the "test2" value in my example? Not trying to give you a hard time, I promise.

Comment: @Tony the results are. "<div style=\"text-align:center;\">test1", " <", "strong>test2", " <", "/strong>test3 test4 test5</div>"

Comment: @ReniCalonge How do mean the results? If you really need the HTML attached to each element of the array I believe the best way to do this is with something like TravisActon's answer. Otherwise I suggest you remove all HTML from the data and split on the remaining spaces.